# send tab & enter, sentences

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to send tab and send enter after Python selenium automation inject username & password shown as below? if I have another form need to fill in sentence "local domain", can I use send_keys("local domain")?

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `Keys` class for this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(Keys.TAB)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```